# Angular JS- Directive Date three field without JQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-directive

Can anyone help me in creating a Angular-js Directive that can handle three field date,

I need a directive for the solution specified in the below link,

http://plnkr.co/edit/lHffXV7xEda0xYorucMe?p=preview

I tried out a couple of solutions and was not rendering properly.

Any plunker illustration would also help. A plunker link is specified below,

http://plnkr.co/edit/lHffXV7xEda0xYorucMe?p=preview

Comment: If all that you need is html template to be stored as different file so here is directive:http://plnkr.co/edit/sia1HAGB8aIytPVD7Juy?p=preview

Comment: Many Thanks - How will the ng-model binding with the back end JSON Obejct will work in this scenario.

Comment: I require to reuse the same date in other places, Is this a standard to use it in this way ?

Comment: Can any one help, I need to pass ng-modiel for three date boxes.

Comment: I didnt quite understand, what the problem you trying to solve: in your example you already have three inputs each attached to some ng-model, what you want to be different?

Comment: I need all the fields to be attached to a single ng-model object with the Format dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) for an example how to implement a custom directive with `ng-model` support. I have created a simple implementation based on this example, you can [see demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfqWnNieb6Cgl8tBrLU2?p=preview).

My current implementation has one drawback - it does not handle invalid dates correctly. To fix this you could either make sure that user cannot enter invalid date or add validation support to the directive via `$formatters` and `$parsers` of `ngModelController`. I guess the latter would not be difficult, if I have time I'll try to do that later.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is the exact this I needed, could you please help me out, with the validators as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and also JQuery shouldnt be used.

Comment: The soultion is excellent, here another query is mhow will I format the DATE TO DD-MM-yyyy to ng-model binding object..?

Comment: I have added validation support and some tests: https://github.com/romario333/datedirective

jQuery is not needed for this directive, the only required dependency is Angular.js.

As to your question about formatting, what do you mean? You don't need to format the value you bind via ng-model, it's always of Date type.

Comment: My requirement is when I specify an ngModel="someVariable", the data binded should be in the format yyyy-MM-dd,

Comment: One option would be to use Angular's date filter, see this example how to invoke it from JavaScript: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLETxObc5YFIeoMfLEUn?p=preview

Comment: Thanks buddy, that was the expected requirement. I am now facing one more issue with the date. How can i onverit the formatted date back to the date object. I have a requirement where in I have the date to be applied to these fields back from json.

Comment: I have sorted it out myself. Thanks Romario.